# AngularJS case-insensitive binding to a static select drop-down

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to perform a case-insensitive bind of an ng-model to a static select drop-down using AngularJS. Consider the select element:

```
<select id="animal" ng-model="ctrl.animal">
    <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
    <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
</select>
```

If I set `ctrl.animal="Cat"` in my Angular Controller the binding works fine. The issue is that if I set `ctrl.animal="CAT"` it does not bind because the strings are not equal as a result of the casing difference.

I've also tried converting the `'value'` attributes to all upper-case but the binding still doesn't work. As-in the sample:

```
<select id="animal" ng-model="ctrl.animal">
    <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
    <option value="CAT">Cat</option>
    <option value="DOG">Dog</option>
</select>
```

Is there a way for AngularJS to ignore case when binding to a select list? Or, at the very least, use the text in the 'value' attribute for binding instead of what's in the `'option'` element tag.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trush44/dwd2du17/)

Comment: Do you want to select the first option of your select?

Comment: No, the actual drop-down has over 20 options. I am getting the model value from an external resource so it could be any one of those +20 options. The value will always be given to me in all uppercase, but I don't want to see all uppercase when actually viewing the rendered HTML.

Comment: So you have a collection with this 'values' and you're using ngOptions, right?

Comment: No, I am not using ng-options. The HTML is static just as in the example above. If the only way to solve this is to use a dynamic 'select' with ng-options then I would consider that, but would prefer not to go that route.

Comment: Can you edit your question posting an example of this static HTML?

Comment: JSFiddle added https://jsfiddle.net/trush44/dwd2du17/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is an optimal way, but you can create a custom formatter that will handle model to view convertion. [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/im228a42GdubkM36n5VI?p=preview).

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .directive('caseinsensitiveOptions', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: ['ngModel', 'select'], 
      link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrls) {
        var ngModel = ctrls[0];

        ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
          var option = [].filter.call(el.children(), function(option) {
            return option.value.toUpperCase() === value.toUpperCase()
          })[0]; //find option using case insensitive search.

          return option ? option.value : value
        });          
      }
    }
  })

  <select id="animal" caseinsensitive-options ng-model="ctrl.animal">
```

Comment: I very much like this! Pretty much what I'm going for. I'll give it some more time and mark this as the answer if nothing else comes along more simplified. Thanks for chiming in!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the option value to uppercase or lowercase so that you know it will always be in a specific case.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('exampleApp', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ExampleController);

  function ExampleController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.dropDownValues = [{
      value: "Cat",
      name: "Cat"
    }, {
      value: "Dog",
      name: "Dog"
    }];
    vm.animal = "CAT";
    /*
    // probably easier to just select the first element
    vm.animal = vm.dropDownValues[0].value;
    */
  }

})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='exampleApp'>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
  <select ng-model="vm.animal" ng-options="(animal.value | uppercase) as animal.name for animal in vm.dropDownValues">
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately not looking to introduce ng-options but want to keep the static HTML. I think Yury has it by introducing the custom formatter.