# AngularJS case-insensitive binding to a dynamic select dropdown without changing the ng-bind value to lower or upper case

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, filter, formatter

I am trying to perform a case-insensitive bind of an ng-model to a dynamic select drop-down using AngularJS.

by going through various other relavent answers from stack over flow, i have come up with something like below on the view , here caseinsensitive-options  is an directive which i have come up with referencing the following solution

[AngularJS case-insensitive binding to a static select drop-down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38343966/angularjs-case-insensitive-binding-to-a-static-select-drop-down)

HTML:

```
<select id="dcName" caseinsensitive-options="" ng-model="DC.name" class="form-control">
  <option value="">--- Please Select ---</option>
  <option ng-repeat="dataCenter in inventoryDataCenters" value="{{dataCenter}}">{{dataCenter}}</option>
</select>
```

js directive code :

```
app.directive('caseinsensitiveOptions', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: ['ngModel', 'select'],
        link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrls) {
          var ngModel = ctrls[0];
          ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
            var option = [].filter.call(el.children(), function(option) {
              return option.value.toUpperCase() === value.toUpperCase()
            })[0];
            return option ? option.value : value
          });

        }
      }
    });
```

The expected result  is

when i pass something like this for 
$scope.inventoryDataCenters = ["TEST1","test2",teST3]; and ng-model for DC.name has value TesT1.

The drop down should show TEST1 by doing case insensitive binding.  That doesnt happen now. The above solution works perfect when we have static drop down.

things to be considered is that the select is inside a div which ng-repeat as shown below

```
ng-repeat="DC in workflowData.project_data.service_info.variables.service_data['data-center']"
```

and ng-model for select DC.name is derived from the above array DC.

Comment: why would you not just sanitize the data rather than try to force the framework to deal with it?  Wouldn't it make more sense to just convert the data to the correct case in the controller before trying to assign it to your model?

Comment: I understand but the requirement is not to change the data .. any other way to do this ?

Comment: I think that fixing the data model so that it's usable in the controller isn't the same as "changing the data", unless you end up persisting the model change, for some reason...  You could always clone the data and use the clone, without having any effect on the original information, it would still be better than trying to do this.

Comment: Thanks Claies. I ended up doing something similar that made things work for me

Comment: I ended up writing an function on page load, which gets the user input that is passed to ng-model and then compares (case insensitive) it with the dynamic drop down data array that is repeated using ng-repeat, if there is match then replace the drop down value with the one user enterd, this takes care that the data in the model is not modified and dropdown list and selects the user eneterd value

Answer (score 0):

check this URL for binding based on case insensitive value

https://jsfiddle.net/dwd2du17/6/

```
 <div ng-app="module" ng-controller="controller as ctrl">
 <select id="animal" ng-model="ctrl.animal">
  <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
  <option value="CaT">Cat</option>
  <option value="DOg">Dog</option>
 </select>
 {{ctrl.animal}}
 </div>


 var appForm = angular.module('module', [])
 .controller('controller', function($scope) {
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for ur input suhas but the above solution will just apply the filter on the view to upper case on the drop down but i need something which can do case insensitive comparison without modyfying the values. The above solution will just change the case on the view